# How can I statistically formulate football player attributes similar to Football Manager games or footballdatabase.eu?

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, games

I have collected player match history statistics like runs, shoots, passes and such. I would like to come up similar attribute values (psychical, mental, technical) to Football Manager game or footballdatabase.eu . What would you suggest to come up such a statistical formulation for each attribute based on known numerical statistics? What are the resources and headings that might be helpful to me ?

Any recommendation, suggestion or comment is very appreciate :)

Here is a example page from football manager.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking ... can you give examples of attribute values for those unfamiliar with the game or the website you mention?

Comment: look at http://www.footballdatabase.eu/football.joueurs..neymar.62381.en.html at the right mid there are the skill ratings that I called attributes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like all of these "attributes", or aspects of the players' overall skill, are calculated by hand-crafted subjective "rules". Clearly a lot of expert knowledge is required to create such rules, and two experts will most likely create two different sets of rules.

If you had some labelled data: i.e. you have skill ratings and you have game statistics (passes etc) for the same players and the same games, you could try to automatically infer the rules. This could be done using [association mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning), or you could do some pre-processing of the game data (e.g. binning into histograms) and then formulate it as a [linear regression](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/linreg.htm) problem.